# Is there a comprehensive list of third-party IDEs and/or debuggers that are officially supported with TFS?

Tags: debugging, tfs, ide

I've been searching the internet, TechNet, MSDN, etc.
But I can't seem to find what I'm looking for.

Has Microsoft published any lists of officially supported debuggers and/or IDEs?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You get Visual Studio through Team Explorer, and Eclipse through the TEE plugin. Then you have the MSSCCI plugin. Those are the only official integrating.

There are then a bunch of third party integrations using either the .NET API, or the Java API. Microsoft don't keep track of those...